# What is the smallest trapezium that contains 5 given circles?

Tags: area

There are 5 circles  with a radius of 3.34 cm each as shown in the picture. What is the trapezium with smallest area that contains these 5 given circles?

[image: a trapezium with the two circles on the top with three on the bottom stacked adjacently]

The image is a trapezium with the two circles on the top with three on the bottom stacked adjacently 
I tried adding the diameters of 3 to get the bottom, 2 to get the top then 2 to get the height but then the angle would cut through the bottom circle. I'm unsure how to figure out what length it has to be

Comment: Please note that the body of the post should be self contained. So move the necessary information from the title to the body of the post. Also you should tell us your thoughts and what you have already tried.

Comment: Well I have tried finding the area of the circles then the minimum lengths for each aspect (a b and h). But the angles at which the trapezium came in toward seemed unrealistic. Sorry for the formatting my first time on this platform

Comment: please add this information to the post. How did you calculte the minmum length of a,b, and h. What property of the trapezoid should become minimal? I assume  the area. Is this right? If so, how is the area of a trapezoid calculated? Please add this to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Just by observation, it's when the sloping sides are tangent to both circles. In the picture, a sloping line which is tangent to both circles will remove more orange area above the tangent point on the bottom circle than the added area below it.